# Why is my value converted from int to char?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, initializer-list

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Person_t{
private:
        uint8_t age;
public:
        void introduce_myself(){
                std::cout << "I am  " << age << " yo" << std::endl;
        }

        Person_t()
                : age{99}
        { };

};

int main(){
        Person_t person1{};
        person1.introduce_myself();
}
```

When the shown code is executed, the integer from the initializer list gets converted to a `c`. I have no explaination why, could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: On your system `std::uint8_t` is probably `typedef`d to `unsigned char` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer _"...std::uint8_t may be unsigned char..."_

Comment: `uint8_t` is a typedef (a type alias) to some `char` type.  As a somewhat common workaround you can use unary `+age` to convert `age` from a `uint8_t` to an `int` on the fly.

Comment: Add a `static_cast<unsigned>` when printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<< age
```

`age` is a `uint8_t`, which is an alias for an underlying native type of a `unsigned char`. Your C++ library implements `std::ostream`'s `<<` overload for an `unsigned char` as a formatting operation for a single, lonely, character.

Simply cast it to an `int`.

```
<< static_cast<int>(age)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! It makes sense. Is it any good btw to use unit8_t in such a context?

Comment: I'm sure there are many situation where using `uint8_t` would be appropriate, so, sure.

Comment: If you really want to use 8 bits storage then yes. IMO it is the most explicit cross platform way to do it.